# Discord.Net C# Discord.Messages[] to string

Tags: c#, bots, spam-prevention, discord, discord.net

I'm trying to make a Spam Filter for a discord server of mine, building it into the bot I already have. This filter will, when finished, delete any 2 consecutive messages that are the same in order to prevent copy and paste spam. So far, I have most of the functionality implemented, but I cannot figure out how to convert `Discord.Messages[]` to strings, in order to properly compare current and past messages. What I have so far looks like this;

```
// Spam Filter

        discord.MessageReceived += async (s, e) =>
        {
            var channel = e.Server.FindChannels("general", ChannelType.Text).FirstOrDefault();
            var user = discord.CurrentUser;
            spamold = spamnew;
            Message[] messagesToObtain;
            messagesToObtain = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(1);
            spamnew = string.Format(messagesToObtain);
            if(spamnew == spamold)
            {
                Message[] messagesToDelete;
                messagesToDelete = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(2);
                await e.Channel.DeleteMessages(messagesToDelete);
            };


        };
```

I'm capable of making enough modifications for the program to *run*, but when it does so it doesn't properly compare strings and so it continually deletes 2 messages for every 1 sent.
*[insert unnecessary rant below]*
 I'm not the best with C#, nor am I in any C language but I understand the very basics such as variable types and the grammatical structure. It's a wonder I've managed to get this far making my bot without the need for actually *asking* for  help on any forums (Well I did once but nobody answered). I would be overjoyed to get this thing working.

Comment: `string.Format(messagesToObtain)` will just turn it into something like `Discord.Net.Message[]` all the time since it's like calling `.ToString()` on an array. Hence it will delete every message since the strings are the same every time. Access the individual message `messagesToObtain[0]` and check if there are any properties that could hold the message contents (such as `.Text`).

Comment: That appears to have worked- thanks!